# Postgres multi table join when tables are capitalized

Tags: postgresql

The software I used created tables in postgres with Capitalizations, and I know that postgres and caps are a pain to deal with. I am using a multi-table query but they have Caps and I am not sure how to get the query down correctly to make it work.

I have two databases TBLS and DBS. I want to get the column TBL_NAME where the two DB_ID's are the same.

Here is what I thought might work:

```
select '"t.TBL_NAME"' from "TBLS" t, "DBS" d where '"t.DB_ID"'='"d.DB_ID"';
```

Any way I try and place the " or ' I can't seem to get the query to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"tablename"."columnname"`

See [the manual on SQL syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

`'"X.COL"'` is a string literal with content string `"X.COL"`.

`"X.COL"` is a single unqualified identifier for the object named `X.COL`. Yes, table, column, etc names can have a `.` in them.

`"X"."COL"` is a qualified identifier for `COL` in object `X`. Depending on context it can mean "the table `COL` in schema `X`", "the column `COL` in table `X`", etc. This is the one you want.